# Equally xaxis spaced and outlier treatmen

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Hello I am new in latex and I am trying to plot some data in equally space values of x, so far I have done this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        bar width=7pt,
        xtick distance=2,
        xlabel=pH,
        xtick=\empty,
        extra x ticks={3.0,3.8,5.2,7.5,10},
        extra x tick labels={3.0,3.8,5.2,7.5,10}]
        ylabel=Size (d.nm),
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.5},

        ymin=0,
        scaled ticks=false,

        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
        },
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (10,15.23)+-(10,0.0346410161513768)
            (7.5,16.8466666666667)+-(7.5,0.14224392195568)
            (5.2,18.1166666666667)+-(5.2,0.187705443004015)
            (3.8,18.6866666666667)+-(3.8,0.14571661996263)
            (3,18.4033333333333)+-(3,0.117189305541646)
        };

        \addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (10,17.66)+-(10,0.174355957741627)
            (7.5,15.4966666666667)+-(7.5,0.0251661147842353)
            (5.2,18.5066666666667)+-(5.2,0.173877351409934)
            (3.8,18.18)+-(3.8,0.0871779788708136)
            (3,18.4966666666667)+-(3,0.0776745346515396)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (10,19.01)+-(10,0.156204993518134)
(7.5,18.7266666666667)+-(7.5,0.11503622617825)
(5.2,19.07)+-(5.2,0.112694276695846)
(3.8,18.39)+-(3.8,0.0871779788708136)
(3,18.7233333333333)+-(3,0.11503622617825)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (10,19.5)+-(10,0.219317121994613)
(7.5,18.6933333333333)+-(7.5,0.0602771377334176)
(5.2,19.2866666666667)+-(5.2,0.0251661147842344)
(3.8,19.4766666666667)+-(3.8,0.0680685928555417)
(3,19.1866666666667)+-(3,0.0404145188432747)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=plus,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (10,65)+-(10,8)
(7.5,64.5633333333333)+-(7.5,4.27418218298347)
(5.2,68.3033333333333)+-(5.2,0.733303029676911)
(3.8,68.02)+-(3.8,0.347706773014274)
(3,72)+-(3,2.80770962411239)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but the spaces are not equally spaced as I have it in Excel[image]. Also, do you know any way to treat the outlier bar? or is better two plots and in one excluding the outlier one.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome! The plot uses the coordinates which you supply it with. You need to use `symbolic coordinates` to achieve the effect you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `symbolic x coords` to create something similar to the excel output. The error bars of the group at pH=10 are enormous. For the time being I suppressed them. To me it seems that there is a possibility that either `y explicit relative` is incorrect or the errors are too large.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=12cm,
        ybar,
        bar width=7pt,
        xlabel=pH,
        symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E},
        xtick={A,B,C,D,E},
        xticklabels={10,7.5,5.2,3.8,3.0},
        ylabel=Size (d.nm),
        enlarge x limits={0.2},
        ymin=0,
        scaled ticks=false,
        xtick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
        }
    ]
        \addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (A,15.23)+-(A,0.0346410161513768)
            (B,16.8466666666667)+-(B,0.14224392195568)
            (C,18.1166666666667)+-(C,0.187705443004015)
            (D,18.6866666666667)+-(D,0.14571661996263)
            (E,18.4033333333333)+-(E,0.117189305541646)
        };

        \addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (A,17.66)+-(A,0.174355957741627)
            (B,15.4966666666667)+-(B,0.0251661147842353)
            (C,18.5066666666667)+-(C,0.173877351409934)
            (D,18.18)+-(D,0.0871779788708136)
            (E,18.4966666666667)+-(E,0.0776745346515396)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (A,19.01)+-(A,0.156204993518134)
            (B,18.7266666666667)+-(B,0.11503622617825)
            (C,19.07)+-(C,0.112694276695846)
            (D,18.39)+-(D,0.0871779788708136)
            (E,18.7233333333333)+-(E,0.11503622617825)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=both,
                y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (A,19.5)+-(A,0.219317121994613)
            (B,18.6933333333333)+-(B,0.0602771377334176)
            (C,19.2866666666667)+-(C,0.0251661147842344)
            (D,19.4766666666667)+-(D,0.0680685928555417)
            (E,19.1866666666667)+-(E,0.0404145188432747)
        };
\addplot+ [
            error bars/.cd,
                y dir=plus,
                %y explicit relative,
        ] coordinates {
            (A,65)+-(A,8)
            (B,64.5633333333333)+-(B,4.27418218298347)
            (C,68.3033333333333)+-(C,0.733303029676911)
            (D,68.02)+-(D,0.347706773014274)
            (E,72)+-(E,2.80770962411239)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, Do you know if is it possible to use the wrapping tool to display many plots in the same figure? thank you in advance

Comment: @JhonnatanRodriguez I am sorry, I do not know what you mean by "wrapping tool". You can use loops or plot the data directly from a table.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't make myself clear.  I want to have multiple plots in the same figure or place. I know that for figures, the subcaption package works for this but for the plots I don't know how to employ it.

Comment: @JhonnatanRodriguez There is the `groupplots` library, which is described in section **5.8 Grouping plots** of the pgfplots manual v1.16.